# Jquery inarray() multiple matches index

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to retrieve the index of an array using jquery inArray() function.
it creates problem when there are two values similar in an array, this function always returns the index of the first match.

```
$testarray1=["car","bike","train"];
$testarray2=["car","boat","car"];
$index=$.inArray($testarray1[1],testarray2);
```

how can i implement something like this which enables me to retrieve the index of the 3rd element of $testarray2?

Comment: You want the index of the last element if there is more than one? -> [`Array.prototype.lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/lastIndexOf)

Comment: `indexOf` only ever returns the first instance found. If you want the last instance, use `lastIndexOf`. If you want all indexes, then you'll need to build your own loop

Comment: `lastIndexOf` will only give last value. If you want all values, try `arrat.reduce((p,c,i)=>{if(c === searchValue) p.push(i); return p}, [])`

Comment: Thank you guys, figured it out.